# Linking tables in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database that links to 6 tables.  These tables are updated weekly and kept in a folder with the date.  I would like for my access program to ask the user to select the location of the tables with out specifically using the Linked Table Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prompt a user for the full path and file name of the database to be linked to. I decided to do this rather than just prompt for a folder. I strongly suggest you look at the connect string for one of your linked tables and make sure no other parameters are specified other than something like ';DATABASE=C:\Foldera\YYMMDD\MyAccessDB.mdb"

```
Private Function ReLinkTables()
Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
Dim tdf             As DAO.TableDef
Dim tdf2            As DAO.TableDef
Dim strConn         As String
Dim strNewPath      As String
Dim strTableName    As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    ' Prompt user for new path...
    strNewPath = GetFolder

    ' Exit if none
    If strNewPath = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
    ' Find all the linked tables...
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        'Debug.Print tdf.Name & vbTab & tdf.Connect
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            strTableName = tdf.Name
            Debug.Print "Linked Table: " & tdf.Name & vbTab & tdf.Connect

            dbs.TableDefs.Delete strTableName         ' Delete the linked table

            strConn = ";DATABASE=" & strNewPath
            Set tdf2 = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(strTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, strTableName, strConn)
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf2
        Else        ' Not a linked table
            'Debug.Print "Keep:    " & tdf.Name & vbTab & tdf.Connect
        End If
    Next tdf

    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set tdf2 = Nothing
    dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing
    MsgBox "Finished Relinking Tables"
Proc_Exit:

    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    Err.Source = "Module_Load_SQLSERVER_DATABASE: ReLinkTables  at Line: " & Erl
    If Err.Number = 9999 Then
        Resume Next
    End If
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume Proc_Exit
    Resume Next
End Function

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        '.InitialFileName = "Z:\xxxxxxxx"           ' You can change to valid start path
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    Debug.Print "User selected path: >" & sItem & "<"
    If sItem = "" Then MsgBox "User did not select a path.", vbOKOnly, "No Path"
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try